# Ошибки в wordpress после перехода на другой хостинг

Tags: php, wordpress

Я перенес свой сайт с CMS WordPress на другой хостинг, после копирования вижу вот такую ошибку. Помогите с решением, пожалуйста
[image: Ошибка wordpress]

Comment: У вас проблема с плагином popup maker. Переименуйте папку с плагином, сайт должен будет загрузиться, если нет других ошибок. А дальше переустановите плагин

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/767561/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B0-wordpress